# xamarin studio android emulator starting take infinite time

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin studio community edition on my macbook pro. when I try to run any sample project on android emulator it takes infinite time.

Can you please suggest. FYI It was working previosuly . Please check  screen shot  [Android emulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F6EM.png)

Answer (score 2):

I would highly suggest using the Xamarin Android Player instead of Google's default emulator manager.

The Xamarin Android Player is much faster and more reliable in my opinion although I have also heard that choosing different Google Play emulator images can make a big difference. Installing HAXM can also speed up the default Intel Google Play emulator images.

Download the Xamarin Android Player from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/).

*Edit: Thanks to @SushiHangover for pointing out the fact that Xamarin deprecated the Xamarin Android Player. SushiHangover suggests using the Genymotion Android emulator which I have heard good things about but have not tried yet.

Comment: It is a shame that Xamarin deprecated that Player (I wish that they would have open sourced when they killed it off), I would recommend looking at GenyMotion as that is the only real OS-X alternative now.

Comment: @SushiHangover Wow, I was not aware they deprecated it. That is really unfortunate. Thanks for the info though, will update the answer.